# My WordPress Site Shows 404 Error When I Try To Post.

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

For more than 4 days now, i cannot publish my WordPress website.
It shows: 404 Error when i try to publish a post in the website or do anything that will load to another page.

Also i cannot work on the widget area because it's not saving any work there.

I have tried re-saving the permalinks and also even deleted the .htaccess file and upload another one and yet no sign of working.

What is the main problem please?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rather simple, but have you checked disk space?

Comment: 1. Check you server error logs. 2. Enable debug mode, and diagnose where the error lies.

Answer (score 0):

404 Errors are usually URL related. Make sure Wordpress and all of your plugins are up to date. I would also change your permalink settings and see what happens.